# Blow up of mean curvature of volume preserving mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Picture below is from Huisken's [The volume preserving mean curvature flow](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:153469/component/escidoc:153468/332762.pdf).

$h_{ij}$ is second fundamental form. $H=g^{ij}h_{ij}$, and $|A|^2=g^{ij}g^{kl}h_{ik}h_{jl}$. How **2.1.Theorem** equal to the red line ? 
Besides, what is come close together ? It means $h_{ij}-h_{kl}\rightarrow 0$ ?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[image]

Comment: Is that the only Theorem in the Section?

Comment: @Thompson   I think so, I have add the web above .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let $\kappa_i$ denote the eigenvalues of the second fundamental form, then $|A|^2 = \sum_i \kappa_i^2$ and $H = \sum_i \kappa_i$. Some algebraic manipulation should then convince you that $$Q := |A|^2 - \frac 1n H^2 = C_n \left(\sum_{i \ne j} (\kappa_i - \kappa_j)^2\right),$$

so $Q$ is some kind of total measurement of the distance between the eigenvalues. Dividing it by $H^2$ we get a scale-invariant measurement, and the theorem then states that

$$ \frac Q {H^2} \lesssim H^{-\delta};$$

so if $H \to \infty$ then $Q / H^2 \to 0$, i.e. the relative difference between the eigenvalues approaches zero.

As an aside, maybe compare this to Hamilton's original paper on Ricci Flow for Ricci-positive 3-manifolds, where an almost identical estimate is shown for the eigenvalues of $\rm Rc$.